# How to set the value of an Azure KeyVault secret using curl

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have previously used curl to retrieve secrets from my Azure KeyVault.

First I retrieve my token and get the url of my keyvault:

```
token=$(curl -s 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net' -H Metadata:true | awk -F"[{,\":}]" '{print $6}')

keyvaulturl="https://myTestKeyVault-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets"
```

I can then access my KeyVault

```
curl -s ${keyvaulturl}/xxx?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"
```

However this is just for getting secrets. Is there any way via curl to update them? Or is it better to use azure cli? What is the best automated form of authentication in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, yes there is.

```bash
# Add secret
$ curl -X PUT \
    -s "https://alice.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretFromCurl?api-version=2016-10-01" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
    --data-ascii '{"value": "sup3rs3cr37v4lu3"}' \
    -H "Content-type: application/json"

{"value":"sup3rs3cr37v4lu3","id": ...


# Read back the secret
$ curl -s "https://alice.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretFromCurl?api-version=2016-10-01" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"

{"value":"sup3rs3cr37v4lu3","id": ...
```

Use [**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) to parse JSON, `awk` does JSON like i do yoga (with sub-optimal gracefulness) —

```bash
$ curl -s "https://alice.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretFromCurl?api-version=2016-10-01" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" | jq -r ".value"

sup3rs3cr37v4lu3
```

However, it's a little cumbersome, using `az keyvault secret ...` is cleaner and more human readable, not to mention `az` has its own built-in JMESPath `--query` filter. For example:

```bash
# Login with Managed Service Identity
$ az login --identity

# Get secret value
$ az keyvault secret show --vault-name alice -n SecretFromCurl --query "value" --output tsv

sup3rs3cr37v4lu3
```

Just in case you needed more manual JSON exploring in your life, [**`jpterm`**](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal) will NOT disappoint —

[image: jpterm screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. Loved the yoga joke!! You mention that using az keyvault is much less cumbersome -- what would you recommend authentication wise for this method?

Comment: Just do this: `az login --identity`. It will login with Managed Service Identity, just like your `curl` example does. If you don't see the parameter you simply need to update `az`.